# How I can receive ad account/campaign/ad set/ad history from Facebook Marketing API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

How I can receive ad account/campaign/ad set/ad history from Facebook Marketing API?
For example, I can see history in Ads manager on campaign level View charts-History. How can I receive it from API?

Comment: please explain in detail what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

The Activities endpoint should be good for you. This should works with several edge (AdAccounts, AdSet,...). As example, for an AdAccounts:

```
act_XXX/activities&fields=object_id,object_name,event_type,event_time
```

See the docs:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-activity
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.3/user/activities
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/application/activities/

hope this help

Comment: Is  there any way to get some operation histories of an account like `account name updating` ?